# How to fix upstream connect error in Consul Mesh?

Tags: kubernetes, consul, servicemesh

I am new to consul. I am trying out few things. I would like to know if this is issue or not.

Currently, I was following `Consul up and Running` Book, and have 2 deployment and services within the mesh i.e frontend and backend.

At any point in time both frontend and backend has only one replicas running, however, in consul UI it seems to be showing four instances.

[image]

[image]

Assuming instances means no. of instances of the  deployments running, it is wrong, right ?

[image]

I believe because of this I am running into such issues.

Running consul on Azure, I usually stop and start cluster, can it be because of that ?
How to fix this issue ?

Thanks in advance